# How to combine Do Until with an Or condition?

Tags: vba

I want to make a set of standards which the generator would have to follow but its saying

> "System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "no" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.'"

```
Dim capitals As String
Do Until capitals = "yes" Or "no"
    Console.WriteLine("do you want your password to include capitals")
    capitals = Console.ReadLine
Loop
```

Comment: `Do Until capitals = "yes" Or capitals = "no"`  You may also want to deal with case use, ie `"Yes"` <> `"yes"` unless you have your setting to compare correctly.  The default setting will not see them as equal.

Comment: Also one piece of clarity, are you using this on Excel, Word, Outlook, etc? or are you using Visual Studios?  `vba` is for applications like Excel, while `vb.net` is used in visual studios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Do Until capitals = "yes" Or capitals = "no"
```

This is because, in programming `or` separates two whole statements which can come out as a Boolean at the end.

The conditions in the original code:
• `Until capitals = "yes"
• "no"

This definitely isn't what you want, you're supposed to have `Until Capitals =` both sides!